# How to read a csv file from google storage using duckdb

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, duckdb

I'm using duckdb version `0.8.0`

I have a CSV file located in google storage `gs://some_bucket/some_file.csv` and want to load this using duckdb.

In pandas I can do `pd.read_csv("gs://some_bucket/some_file.csv")`, but this doesn't seem to work in duckdb. I see that there's some documentation here: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/s3_import.html, but I find that confusing as it's mainly aimed at `s3` usage.

I guess that I have to run:

```py
duckdb.sql("INSTALL httpfs;")
duckdb.sql("LOAD httpfs;")
```

From the documentation, I'm not sure what the parameters for :

```
SET s3_access_key_id='key_id';
SET s3_secret_access_key='access_key';
```

Would be.

How do I load a csv from google storage in duckdb?

### Edit - approaches which haven't worked

I've added `hmac` keys and downloaded them following guide here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/managing-hmackeys#gsutil_1

```py
import duckdb
import os

duckdb.sql("LOAD httpfs;")

hmac_access = os.getenv('GOOGLE_HMAC_ACCESS_ID')
hmac_secret = os.getenv('GOOGLE_HMAC_SECRET')

duckdb.sql(f"SET s3_access_key_id='{hmac_access}';")
duckdb.sql(f"SET s3_secret_access_key='{hmac_secret}';")


################################################################################
# approach 1

# Doesn't work - fails with:
# 
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "duck_test.py", line 18, in <module>
#     duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM '{gcp_path_1}'").show()
# duckdb.CatalogException: Catalog Error: Table with name {gcp_path_1} does not exist!
# Did you mean "pg_am"?

# duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * FROM '{gcp_path_1}'").show()


################################################################################
# approach 2

# Fails with:

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "duck_test.py", line 32, in <module>
#     duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * from read_csv('{gcp_path_1}', AUTO_DETECT=TRUE);")
# duckdb.HTTPException: HTTP Error: HTTP GET error on 'https://some_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some_file.csv' (HTTP 400)

duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * from read_csv('{gcp_path_1}', AUTO_DETECT=TRUE);")
```

### Edit (working)

In the code above I forgot to set

```py
duckdb.sql("SET s3_endpoint='storage.googleapis.com'")
```

After setting this both approaches read from storage.

Comment: check https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/managing-hmackeys

Comment: Your approach one is failing with a catalog error because you forgot to add the `f` prefix to the f-string for the SQL string

Answer (score 4):

To access your files, you need to use **s3** as the URL prefix.

1. If your GCS bucket is open to the public

```py
duckdb.sql('INSTALL httpfs')
duckdb.sql('LOAD httpfs')

duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM 's3://some_bucket/some_file.csv'").show()
```

2. If your GCS bucket is not public.
   First, you need to set an HMAC key. Go to
   [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/settings;tab=interoperability) and follow the instructions. Then, execute the following commands

```py
duckdb.sql('INSTALL httpfs')
duckdb.sql('LOAD httpfs')
duckdb.sql("SET s3_endpoint='storage.googleapis.com'")

# You will obtain the key_id from the previous step of 
# configuring settings in the Google Console.
duckdb.sql("SET s3_access_key_id='<your-key-id>'") 

# You will obtain the secret_access_key from the previous step of 
# configuring settings in the Google Console.
duckdb.sql("SET s3_secret_access_key='<your-key>'") 

duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM 's3://some_bucket/some_file.csv'").show()
```

Comment: Running that gives the error: `duckdb.CatalogException: Catalog Error: Table with name {gcp_path_1} does not exist!`, here `gcp_path_1` is set to: `s3://storage_bucket/some_file.csv` (I've changed `storage_bucket/some_file.csv` to a path that exists in my storage though)

Comment: I've updated the OP with context on the failure

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fsspec](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) to access GCS.
DuckDB's [integration with fsspec](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/filesystems.html) lets you query data from a wider range of filesystems than its built-in httpfs extension alone. fsspec offers numerous filesystem options, both built-in and through external plugins.

After installing the required packages

```
pip install duckdb fsspec gcsfs
```

You can register GCS as additional file system and use duckdb to query the files

```
import duckdb
from fsspec import filesystem

# this line will throw an exception if the appropriate filesystem interface is not installed
duckdb.register_filesystem(filesystem('gcs'))

duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM read_csv('gcs:///bucket/file.csv')")
```

This also works nicely with packages like [jupysql in Jupyter Notebooks](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/python/jupyter.html)

```
%%sql
df << SELECT 
    t1.movieId,
    t1.title,
    t1.genres,
    t2.userId,
    t2.rating,
    t3.tag
  FROM 'gcs:///bucket/movies/movies.csv' AS t1
  INNER JOIN 'gcs:///bucket/movies/ratings.csv' AS t2 USING (movieId)
  INNER JOIN 'gcs:///bucket/movies/tags.csv' AS t3 USING (userId, movieId)
```